# Scala: How can I catch an exception thrown by a parent class's constructor?

Tags: scala

Say I have the following:

```
class Parent {
  // does some things that may result in an exception
  throw new IllegalArgumentException
}

class Child extends Parent
```

I'd like for `Child`'s constructor to catch, wrap, and rethrow the exception thrown by `Parent`'s constructor.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to do exactly what you want. The invocation of the `Parent` constructor by `Child` is controlled solely by the `extends` portion of the `Child` declaration, and secondary `Child` constructors can call the `Parent` constructor only via the primary `Child` constructor (see [this Scala Cookbook entry](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch04s12.html))

As an alternative, though, you can make the `Child` constructor private and instead instantiate `Child` via a factory method that wraps any exceptions thrown:

```
class Child private extends Parent

object Child {
  def apply() = {
    try {
      new Child
    } catch {
      case e: IllegalArgumentException => throw new WrappedException(e)
    }
  }
}

val foo = Child() // throws WrappedException
```

Note that this will also catch, wrap, and re-throw any `IllegalArgumentException` thrown by the constructor of Child itself.

Comment: s/Unfortunately/fortunately. If you could catch during construction, this is in unknown state.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for:

```
scala> class Parent(i: Int) { if (i > 40) throw new IllegalArgumentException }
defined class Parent

scala> new Parent(0)
res0: Parent = Parent@3e74829

scala> new Parent(42)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
  ... 29 elided

scala> class Child extends Parent({ try new Parent(42) catch { case _: IllegalArgumentException => throw new RuntimeException }; 42})
defined class Child

scala> new Child
java.lang.RuntimeException
  at Child.liftedTree1$1(<console>:12)
  ... 29 elided
```

but it suggests

```
scala> class Parent(val i: Int) { def this(p: Parent) = this(p.i) ; if (i > 40) throw new IllegalArgumentException }
defined class Parent

scala> class Child extends Parent({ val p = try new Parent(42) catch { case _: IllegalArgumentException => throw new RuntimeException }; p})
defined class Child

scala> new Child
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    Child.<init>()V @2: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type uninitializedThis (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'Child'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @2
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis }
    stack: { uninitializedThis, uninitializedThis }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2a b700 254c 2bb7 0028 b1

  ... 28 elided
```

OK, never mind.